# c++ arrays and loops

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I am given 'n' names of students, then 'k' amount of tasks they've got marks for. Each task has its own coefficient(e.g. if there are 4 tasks, there are 4 coefficients: 0.2; 0.3; 0.3; 0.4), so the amount of coefficients is also 'k'. My job is to:

1. Read 'n'(the amount of students) and 'k' (amount of tasks);
2. Read  all of the coefficients(that I will have to multiply with each mark of each student later);
3. Read the specific name and the 'k' amount of marks each student got and,as I've said, multiply each mark with the coefficient. Coefficients are static. After doing that, I have to sum all of the 4 multiplications I have done for 1 student and it will be his final grade. How do I assign finamark[0] for name[0] and so on? I have trouble getting the final mark

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
   int main(){

   int n, k, b = 0;
   double coefficients[10], marks[10], final[30] = {0};
   string name, names[30];

   cin >> n >> k;               //reading the amount of students n tasks
   for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){  //reading coefficients
       cin >> coefficient[i];
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){    //reading names
     cin.ignore(80, '\n');
     getline(cin,name);
     names[i] = name;
     for (int j = b; j < k; j++){   //reading marks
       cin >> marks[j];
       marks[j] *= coefficient[j];   // trying to get the final mark for each students
       finalmark[j] += marks[j];
     }
     b += k;
     k += k;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Use std::vector isntead of arrays.

Comment: Title says _array and loops_, so **what** exactly is the question?

Comment: IMHO, a better method is to have a vector of structures rather than multiple arrays.  Example: `struct Course { std::string name; double coefficient; double mark;};`.

Comment: Please edit your post with the text of a sample of your input data.

Answer (score 0):

Without any accurate information about your input, I guess you should change the second for loop to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){    //reading names
  cin.ignore(80, '\n');
  getline(cin,name);
  names[i] = name;
  for (int j = 0; j < k; j++){   //reading marks
    cin >> marks[j];
    marks[j] *= coefficient[j];   // trying to get the final mark for each students
    finalmark[j] += marks[j];
  }
}
```

Short explanation:

- You always want to read exactly `k` marks for each student, so `k` should never be incremented.
- You probably access the `marks` and `finalmarks` arrays out of bounds. They have only 10 items and `j` can be greater than 10 because of increment `b`, e.g.: if there are 4 tasks and 10 students, when `i` is `3`, then j starts from `12`, but `marks[12]` is out of bounds.
- I don't know what is the purpose of `b`, but in my opinion it is
  useless. If you would like to know the number of read marks, it's `n*k`.

On the other hand, you should consider using [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead of raw arrays.